# javascript - Ember and Require.JS optimizer "Error: Could not find module jquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, requirejs

I have an Ember application using require.js which is working correctly in the browser before optimization, but when I try to run it through r.js for optimization, I'm receiving an error from Ember: "Error: Could not find module jquery".

I looked a little deeper and it seems like the jQuery and $ global variables aren't defined by the time r.js attempts to eval() Ember.

It's failing when Ember is being required from a handlebars plugin that I've slightly modified to use Ember.Handlebars instead of regular Handlebars (modified version of this: https://github.com/epeli/requirejs-hbs/blob/master/hbs.js)

My current build configuration is:

```
({
  name: 'main',
  out: 'main.min.js',
  optimize: 'uglify2',
  baseUrl: '../static/js/',

  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.11.0',
    handlebars: 'lib/handlebars-1.3.0',
    ember: 'lib/ember-1.5.1',
    hbs: 'plugin/hbs',
    text: 'plugin/text-2.0.12',
  },
  shim: {
    handlebars: {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    },
    ember: {
        deps: [ 'jquery', 'handlebars' ],
        exports: 'Ember'
    }
  },
  hbs: {
    templateExtension: '.html',
  }
})
```

The full error from r.js is:

```
Error: Could not find module jquery
In module tree:
    main
      app/App
        app/view/MainView
          hbs

at t (eval at <anonymous> (r-2.1.11.js:25343:38), <anonymous>:10:374)
```

I've also tried including "wrapShim: true" in my build config, but with no success...

**Edit**:
*I tried removing 'ember' from the dependencies in my hbs plugin, and found an issue with the "include" line I had in my build config, so I removed that line and was able to build successfully. However, adding 'ember' back into the deps for hbs still caused the original issue to come back...*

**Edit 2**:
*It appears that node and r.js do not load jQuery. I assume this is why Ember is unable to find jQuery at build-time. The issue is referenced here:*

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/85

*I may need to find a way to stub out the jQuery dependency so I can use Ember's Handlebars compiler at build time without it...*

Does anybody know how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but have you tried to great a shim for jQuery?

```
shim:{  
    'jquery': {
      deps: [],
      exports: 'jQuery'
    },
...
}
```

Cheers,
Johannes